# Prototypal Inheritance: Why is false not equal to false?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I quickly drafted a little helper method to make undefined variable checks a little easier.

```
Object.prototype.is = function() {
   for(var i in arguments) {
       if(this === arguments[i]) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
};
```

Designed be used like this: `foo.is(undefined, false)` to check whether foo was undefined or false. The test case I used was:

```
var a = false;
a.is(false);
> false
```

Slightly confused, I played around with it a bit more. Some console.logging revealed that the equality checks were failing because the two objects being compared were not the same.

```
Boolean {is: function} === false
> false
```

So, `a` had inherited the `is` method from it's great-grandfather: Object.prototype but the `false` within the comparison had not.

I figured I could force the inheritance through using `new Boolean(false)` which would definitely create a new instance of an object (hopefully circumventing any risk that may occur with references to objects that were created before Object's prototype was extended). The result:

```
Boolean {is: function} === Boolean {is: function}
> false
```

**Why are the equality checks failing?**

As part of the process for working out what was going on here I inspected the arguments array after the function was called with a single boolean value as an argument, only to find that it was of length two, with the extra argument being the `is` function that was declared within Object.prototype.

```
a.is(false);
arguments -> [false, is: function]
```

**How did that end up there?**

For the reference, I know monkey-patching like this is a bad idea! This isn't production code, I'm just interested.

Comment: You should iterate `arguments` like this: `for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)` not the way you are doing it.  Further objects only pass `===` or `==` when they are the exact same object (not just when they have the same contents, but are physically different objects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's the problem?

This is yet another issue with the `this` value being coerced to an object - the monkey patch would be to add `'use strict'` to the start of your function, which prevents this coercion from occurring. However, older browsers may not recognise this directive.

If the function is not strict, here is essentially what happens:

```
var a = false;
Object.prototype.is.call(Object(a), undefined, false);
```

When `a` is converted to an object (by calling `Object(a)`), it is turned into a boolean object, which is different from a boolean value. For example, take this:

```
false === new Boolean(false); // false
```

Also, objects are only equal when they reference the same object:

```
new Boolean(false) === new Boolean(false); // false
var test = new Boolean(false);
test === test; // true, they are the same object
```

Another issue that occurs is that when your `is()` function is called with `null` (and it isn't strict), it will fail:

```
Object.prototype.is.call(null, null); // becomes window === null (false)
```

### What can I do about this?

Alternatives to making it a strict function include comparing the object value of both (though this makes something like `new Boolean(false).is(false)` and `new Boolean(false).is(new Boolean(false))` become true, which may be unintended.

Another alternative that you could take would be to make it a non-prototypal function, that is to make it something like `Object.is` instead (though beware that ES6 is likely to define a native `Object.is` function that will behave differently to your one):

```
Object.oneIsEqual = function (arg, compare)
{   for(var i = 0; i < compare.length; ++i) if (arg === compare[i]) return true;
    return false;
};
```

#### Note about your edit:

The reason why you were getting your original function in the `for-in` loop is because you've defined it on the prototype, and it is enumerable (more on that in a sec).

The `arguments` object has a prototype that is `Object.prototype`, which allows the `is` function to be accessible on `arguments`.

```
Object.prototype.is = function() {
   for(var i in arguments) {
       if(this === arguments[i]) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
};
(function () { return arguments.is; })(); // is the same function as to Object.prototype.is
```

By default (when you define it "normally"), all properties (whether directly on the object or on on the prototype chain) will be enumerable, which means that you can see it in a `for-in` loop and other similar constructs. However, this (most of the time) is not the desired behaviour - most native prototype functions are not enumerable. To work around this, you should run through the indexes of the function, not the properties:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) // code here
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the explanation. I've slightly updated the question, with another oddity that showed up. Any idea?

Comment: @DanPrince: I've edited my answer to cover what I think you're talking about.

Comment: Another option is before doing the comparison to check if `this instanceof Boolean/Number/String` in which case, use this.valueOf() in the comparison. Or to avoid triggering on inherited classes (if this is a concern), check `this.constructor`...

Comment: @FabioBeltramini: that has the same issue that I discussed in my answer - `new Boolean(false).valueOf() === false` is true, when they are _not_ the same.

Comment: I understand the enumerable thing, but this is irrespective of the for-in. If I remove the loop from the body of the function the value of the arguments array won't change. I understand that the arguments array should have an `is` method, but that should appear as a property of the "array" rather than an element, right?

Comment: @DanPrince: it shows up like that as your console most likely does the equivalent of a for-in loop to see the elements in there.